# Weblogic server slow performance

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I'm about to go live with an application, and for the last couple of weeks, the weblogic I installed on my Linux server has been running fine. Until yesterday when suddenly, web service calls were taking too long. I checked the server logs and I couldn't see any requests for the web services. Then I tried to log into the weblogic console and after 6 mins, the console still hadn't loaded up on the browser.

I checked the server logs and there were no errors. Everything seemed normal, but it wasn't. The applications on the weblogic server were either not responding to external web service calls or they were too slow in responding (none of them were throwing errors, by the way). Weblogic itself wasn't complaining about anything.

Weird thing is, when this happened, I shut down the node manager and tried restarting it, but it wouldn't come on completely, like it was stuck. I had to restart the entire red hat OS before weblogic and the nodemanager became responsive.

I want to know, is there something I should be tuning on my weblogic to avoid something like this from repeating?

Beyond this, response from the weblogic server has been amazing. The REDHAT has over 64gb worth of RAM and other crazy configurations.

Comment: First, check you start your server with the following property : -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom otherwise, it will run very slowly under linux.

Comment: It's happening again right now. Java is using up 779% of the CPU according to the "top" command on linux. That's, on average, more than 90% of every core (there are 8 on the server). Where do I put this line: " -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom" in weblogic?

Comment: Update the setDomainEnv.sh and add the property to the JAVA_OPTIONS env var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything Emmanuel Collin said is correct. I also ensured that I stopped all web application services first before either updating the war files or shutting down the servers. That way there were no memory leaks.

Thanks Emmanuel.